# Wirelessly printing without a router

Tags: printing, ipad

I need to print wirelessly from an iPad.  Ideally this setup will be as simple as possible.

Do I have to have a router or are there printers out there that the iPad can just print directly to?

I don't need internet connectivity and there isn't a desktop in that space.

Comment: By "router" you apparently mean "wireless router".  A plain "router" won't help you at all.  It's the "wireless access point" component of a "wireless router" that you need.  In theory a printer could incorporate a WAP.

Comment: @sawdust: Yes, I'd rather not need a wireless router at all.  Do you know of any printers that act as their own access point?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but there is no way to wirelessly print to ANY printer without both devices being on the same wireless network.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible directly... it is called an ad-hoc network (networking a device directly without a router)

```
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2792976
```

Here is the relevant quote from the site:

```
For example HP D110.
```

HP D110 Info Page

See Page 31 of User Guide...

HP D110 User's Manual

Here is how to set up an ad hoc network form there instruction manual.

1. In the Control Panel, double-click Network and Internet, then Network and
   Sharing Center..
2. In the Network and Sharing Center (under Tasks on the left), select Set up a
   connection or network.
3. Choose the connection option Set up a wireless ad hoc (computer-to-computer)
   network, then click Next. Read the description and warnings about ad hoc networks,
   then click Next>.
4. Enter details, including Network name (the SSID for your ad hoc connection),
   Security type, and SecurityPassphrase. If you are going to save this network
   connection, check Save this network. Make a note of the SSID and the Security key/
   Passphrase for future reference. Click Next
5. Continue to follow the prompts to complete setup of the ad hoc network connection.

Comment: That particular thread mentions success with iPads...